# RAII issue regarding resource manager class

Tags: c++, c++11, raii

I have a `SDL_Window` wrapper class called `WindowHandler` as a class member in my `Game` class. Preferably, I would like to initialize the `WindowHandler` in my `Game::init` method. However, the class does not have a 0-param ctor, so the program will break if I don't initialize the `WindowHandler` variable in an initialization list. Is there a way to delay the initialization to the `Game::init` method?

Comment: The purpose of RAII is to not delay initialization but have it done when you create the object.

Comment: X-Y problem, why you need to delay the initialization?

Comment: Simple solution: do not use an `init` method in your `Game` class, but rather the constructor for initialization purposes. Then, you can initialize members of the `Game` class in its constructor, too.

Comment: It seems cleaner to initialize everything in the `init` function to me... but if there's no way around it then I guess I'll init everything in the ctor

Comment: It is a violation of RAII. You will end up with `Game` objects that are invalid because they have not been initialized. This is avoided by doing initialization in the ctor. Why is a separate method "cleaner"?

Comment: It's just my personal opinion, having all "initializations" done in an `init()` method. I will take all your advice into consideration, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The general solution to this is to have

```
unique_ptr<WindowHandler> window;
```

instead of plain

```
WindowHandler window;
```

member, then you can call its constructor with delay.

```
void Game::init(int arg) {
    window = make_unique<WindowHandler>(arg);
}
```

and it will still be destroyed automatically.

(I'm technical here, if this is a good or bad design or if it is a violation of RAII is out of current scope).

Comment: I think this is a good answer. For future reference, it looks like [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/~optional) could work too, as it also calls the dtor. It's possible to imagine implementations of `optional` that don't require dynamic memory allocations, though, so it might have some advantage.